# SQL Server export wizard default mapping for datetime column is wrong

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition. When i tried to export my database to a 2014 Developer Edition instance, somehow its default column mapping changed all my **datetime** columns to **smalldatetime**. Is there anyway i can config the default mapping ?

Comment: How are you exporting the data?

Comment: Nevermind!  I missed the title...

Comment: If you are exporting to an existing table you need to update the data type in the target table.  If the target table is created during the export you can update the data type by clicking *Edit Mappings...* on the *Select Source Tables and Views* screen.